# UICollectionViewLayout Not working with UIImage in Swift 5 and Xcode 11

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiimageview, uiimage, uicollectionviewlayout

Please check this attached code and screen short. It's work fine when I set the color of container view but when I add UIImage in cell then it's not working. I changed the imageview content mode but it's not working.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var segColumn: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

fileprivate var items: [UIImage] = [ // My images ]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setup()
}
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.imgCell.image = items[indexPath.row]
    cell.imgCell.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .red
    return cell
}
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: (collectionView.bounds.width/3 - 2), height: (collectionView.bounds.width/3))
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 2
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 2
    }
}
```

[image: Not working with UIImage]

[image: working when remove UIImage]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please try this solution. I think there are some changes from Xcode 11.
Change the CollectionView Estimate Size to None then it will work.

[image: Please select your storyboard file]

Comment: I had kind of the same issue and I was searching for hours to fix this problem. This fixed my issue and now I can go to sleep. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it is probably because the red is dominating over the image

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.imgCell.image = items[indexPath.row]
    cell.imgCell.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .red
    return cell
}
```

try:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .red
    cell.imgCell.image = items[indexPath.row]
    cell.imgCell.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    return cell
}
```

Comment: No if i comment the imageview code then it works .. i check that with adding content view color. but i add uIImageview then it doesn't work got or not?

Comment: i try your code not working .. anyother solution thank you :)

Comment: what happens when u take out the color?

Comment: It showing me like in Screen short UIImage Screen short.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: assuming that those images are being referenced by an Array, I would assume its an issue with your array. or how you are referencing those images in general. try adding  them inside your array.    you can try to do something like  :    items += [UIImage(named: "imageName.png")!]                   Also I love your YouTube channel :)

Comment: i try this it's not working..Thank You "Youtube" :)

Comment: Hii please check my answer.. i think in xcode 11 changes.. Thanks for your help :)