# Can't Set Cell Size in Collection View inside Table View

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a Table View with 4 cells. In cell 3 & 4 I have a collection view. I am trying to setup the collection view in Table View Cell 4, however for some reason whatever device I select in the interface builder is what get's referenced when I try to set the cell size.

In the TableViewController I have this code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout

        let totalSpace = flowLayout.sectionInset.left
            + flowLayout.sectionInset.right
            + (flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing * 3)

        let size = (collectionView.frame.width - totalSpace) / 4

        return CGSize(width: size, height: 166)
    }
```

Divide the cells into 4 with a height of 166. However, the **collection view.frame.width is NOT referencing the actual collection view**, it's referencing whatever the size was in interface builder.

When run, the cell size is dependant on the collectionview.frame.width, and that value, is wrong.

I have tested this both on the simulator and a device.
Not sure what's going on here?

### **UPDATE:**

I've identified what's causing the issue, but not sure how to fix it. I'm setting the collection view's height constraint based on the content height size:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let topCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "topCell", for: indexPath)

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 1:
        return secondCell
    case 2:
        let collectionViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "matchesCell", for: indexPath) as! collectionViewCellCustomClass

        let height = collectionViewCell.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
        collectionViewCell.heightConstant.constant = height
        self.view.setNeedsLayout()

        return collectionViewCell
    default:
        return topCell
    }
}
```

[image]

This tells the collection view height to be whatever the height is of it's content. I set this in the tableView cell. However, whenever I remove this bit of code, the cell sizing works fine?

Comment: add screenshot of your result

Comment: have you did this on your collectionView?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59188406/8201581

Comment: @YogeshPatel No it's just an empty collection view. I'll add a screenshot.

Comment: Found what is causing the issue, updated.

Comment: estimated size is none or not of your collectionview.

Comment: @YogeshPatel estimated size of collection view cell has no impact, ive tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was solved. Really simply actually:

If I set: collectionView.reloadData() it fixes it!