# collection view cell spacing not working on all devices

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I have a collection view where two cells are in a row. Both have the same size and I want to have the same distance between them no matter how many cells are in the collection view.
Now I have found out that the distance only does not work with the iPhone 11 Pro. Be it on a real device or in a simulator.

Here are two images facing this problem:

[image]

[image]

This is my code for the size and spacing:

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if storeModel.count != 0 {
        let bounds = collectionView.bounds
        let heightVal = self.view.frame.height
        let widthVal = self.view.frame.width
        let cellsize = (heightVal < widthVal) ?  bounds.height/2 : bounds.width/2
        
        return CGSize(width: cellsize - 10   , height:  cellsize - 10  )
    } else {
        let width = collectionView.frame.width
        let height = collectionView.frame.height
        return CGSize(width: width - 20, height: height)
    }

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout. You can add all these parameters and much more.

Comment: What’s the difference?

Comment: I found a solution that helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59181037/uicollectionviewlayout-not-working-with-uiimage-in-swift-5-and-xcode-11/59188406#59188406

Comment: I have a github repo that I made for another question which uses the flow layout. Could be useful for you to take a look at: https://github.com/williamfinn/HorizontalCollectionExample There is much more flexibility in flowlayout which will allow you to make very complex layouts.